# Pictures folder on iMac has a 4 GB Photo Library

Tags: macos, icloud, photos, photos.app

In my `Home` directory on my iMac I have a `Pictures` folder. In it is a 4 GB Photo Library named `Photos Library.photoslibrary`. I have iCloud Photo Library turned on, and it has been on for more than a year.

Why do I have this 4 GB photo library on my iMac? Shouldn't all photos be in iCloud? Can I delete it or should I just leave it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave it. **Photos** still needs to download your Photos when you decide to view them. It will either download a device-optimized or full-resolution copy depending on your chosen settings.

Think of this file as a *local cache* of your photo library, although it also contains other things that are not stored in iCloud, such as *Smart Albums* and facial recognition data. If you delete this file **Photos** will need to recreate it and rebuild your library from iCloud data. In particular, it will need to re-download thumbnails for all of your photos.

The idea is that if you do run low on storage, **Photos** will start purging photos you haven’t viewed in a while, in albums you haven’t specifically marked as `Download Originals to this Mac`.

Comment: Phong, I don't mind the edits but some of them were not necessary. I used names as they appeared on my computer.  I wrote users directory because that is the name on my computer, Same for the pictures folder. The term I used for Photos Library.photoslibrary was a direct copy of the name.  Why change those?

Comment: @john My apologies. Please feel free to rollback if I’ve made any mistakes. The Pictures folder is normally located under your Home folder (**/Users/<your account>**) rather than directly under **Users**. The **Pictures** folder is capitalized on a default install, which is why I changed it. I didn’t realize it was different on your system. As for the last one it was only a formatting change, and if you dislike that once again I apologize.

Comment: No problem. I'll just leave them.